# Sub-view composition life cycle. Running code in sub-view after parent composition has completed

Tags: durandal, composition

I'm working on implementing a left navigation on a subset of views using stacked Bootstrap pills. I'm using a simple `compose` binding to add the left navigation view to a view:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: 'left-nav' }"></div>
```

Within the left navigation, I want to programmatically add the `active` class to one of the pills to indicate which view is active; something like:

```
switch (router.activeInstruction().fragment) {
    case "foo":
        $("#pills #foo").addClass("active");
        break;
};
```

When this code runs in the `activate` handler, the parent view composition hasn't completed yet.

What's the right way to use `compositionComplete` to ensure that this code runs after both the parent and child are fully composed?

Thank you!

**Update:**
Solved... what a difference a few minutes makes - you just need to implement the handler.

```
var compositionComplete = function () {
    switch (router.activeInstruction().fragment) {
        case "foo":
            $("#pills #foo").addClass("active");
            break;
    };
};

var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    compositionComplete: compositionComplete,
};
```

Comment: thats excactly right. the activate callback is more for initializing data, where the composition complete is more for initializing widgets in the html